# String and replace

Tags: c++, c++11

here a little code:

`itr2=s.replace(itr2-5, itr2+1, newVal.begin(), newVal.end()).begin();`
here begin() returns iterator on string, in my case this will be the string not from begining of origin string 's'. I wonder after replace() i get reference on not of begin or reference on a copy.

And i wondering return of s.replace(...) is a part of s?

Comment: Every string has its own contents. You can't have references between the characters of strings.

Comment: You mean that it will be the same string?

Comment: No, every string is different.

Comment: It's copying characters. Characters can't be references to each other.

Comment: So, s.replace(...) not the part of s?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question. I thought you were asking if the values from `newVal` are copied or references.

Answer (score 3):

`s.replace()` returns a reference back to s. Your statement is equivalent to

```
s.replace(itr2-5, itr2+1, newVal.begin(), newVal.end());
itr2 = s.begin();
```

Nothing sneaky is going on.